# A* search algorithm in PHP

Tags: php, algorithm, path-finding, a-star

Does anyone have an implementation of the [A* algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%2A_search_algorithm) in PHP? I know that wikipedia has a pseudocode and a link to a C++ one, but I can't seem to find one already written in PHP.

I am also looking for an efficient written A* algorithm

Comment: I bet linking to the algorithm in your question would help anyone that feels ambitious to make a port. -- EDIT: `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm`

Comment: there's nothing there, it's a wiki page...

Comment: @Equinox: It drops the * in the URL. Add it back after the A, it should work.

Comment: I know, but that's not a PHP implementation... saw that link already

Comment: Sounds kind of easy enough to write, once you understand it. (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kw8AMmyc6vg)

Comment: The speed of A* depends a lot on your datastructure. 
Your question is impossible to answer if you don't explain what your datastructure looks like. once you've cleared that out and have your heuristic function ready it's really as simple as porting the pseudo-code from the wikipedia page mentioned by Brad.

Comment: what do you mean by data structure here? the set of nodes - edge? If that's the case then I have that already in the database as nodes - edge

Comment: github repo with a sample a-star class https://github.com/jmgq/php-a-star