# A* implementation in PHP validation

Tags: php, algorithm, shortest-path, a-star

This is a code that I got from the site [here](http://codezilla.com/projects/a-star/) and I'd like to know whether this implementation of A* is correct. I have looked at it and compare it with the wikipedia page and it seems valid.. The reason why I ask is because in the site it says there is still a bug in this code, I tried finding it but can't find any. I want to change it though so that it takes an origin and destination as input parameter

```
<?php

class AStarSolver
{
    function solve(&$s)
    {
        include_once('PQueue.class.php');
        $o = new PQueue();
        $l = array();
        $c = array();
        $p = array();
        $a = $s->getStartIndex();
        $z = $s->getGoalIndex();
        $d = $s->goalDistance($a);

        $n0 = array('g'=>0, 'h'=>$d, 'i'=>$a, 'p'=>NULL, 'f'=>$d);
        $o->push($n0, -$d);
        $l[$a] = TRUE;

        while (! $o->isEmpty())
        {
            $n = $o->pop();

            if ($n['i'] == $z)
            {
                while ($n)
                {
                    $p[] = $n['i'];
                    $n = $n['p'];
                }
                break;
            }

            foreach ($s->getNeighbors($n['i']) as $j => $w)
            {
                if ((isset($l[$j]) || isset($c[$j])) && isset($m) && $m['g'] <= $n['g']+$w)
                    continue;

                $d = $s->goalDistance($j);
                $m = array('g'=>$n['g']+$w, 'h'=>$d, 'i'=>$j, 'p'=>$n, 'f'=>$n['g']+$w+$d);

                if (isset($c[$j]))
                    unset($c[$j]);

                if (! isset($l[$j]))
                {
                    $o->push($m, -$m['f']);
                    $l[$j] = TRUE;
                }
            }
            $c[$n['i']] = $n;
        }
        return $p;
    }

}

?>
```

The code to the Pqueue can be found [here](http://codetidy.com/443)

Comment: No idea why you were downvoted; this isn't a bad topic per se. However code and algorithm verifications are not quite on-topic for Stackoverflow. Thus you could eventually delete & move this question to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @mario Not entirely, Code Review requires that you have *working code*, so bug spotting isn't entirely within it's purview.

Comment: Have you tried to contact codezilla to ask him about his implementation? Having been downvoted for suggesting this to you when you first asked about A* in PHP: I still think it looks like a valid implementation. But I'll wait to see what other people say about it.

Comment: Yea... I don't see why it's down voted... I think it's a valid question... if it needs to be moved to codereview then be it. The code is working... it just doesn't work for some cases

Comment: @Mark Baker yes and no reply yet

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The site suggests that the bug might be in the `PQueue` class.

In `PQueue::pop` this

```
$j+1 < $m
```

is a test whether the heap node at `$i` has one child (at `$j`) or two (at `$j` and `$j+1`).

But `$m` here is `count($h)` only on the first iteration through the loop, since the `--$m` in the loop condition is evaluated every time.

Move that `--$m` next to the `array_pop` where it belongs, and that will be one less bug.

---

Now for `AStarSolver`.

The variables are (relative to [Wikipedia pseudocode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%2a_search_algorithm?oldid=416264305#Pseudocode)):

- `$o` – open set as priority queue;
- `$l` – open set as map keyed by index;
- `$c` – closed set as map keyed by index;
- `$n` – current node (*x*);
- `$m` – neighbour node (*y*) ?;
- `$j` – neighbour node index.

Problems that I see:

- `$n = $o->pop()` isn't followed by `unset($l[$n['i']])`. Since both `$o` and `$l` represent the same set, they should be kept in sync.
- According to Wikipedia the closed set is only used if the heuristic is *monotone* (and I think a distance heuristic is monotone), and in that case, once a node is added to the closed set, it is never visited again. This code seems to implement some [other pseudocode](http://www.heyes-jones.com/pseudocode.html), which does remove nodes from the closed set. I think this defeats the purpose of the closed set, and the first condition in the inner loop should be

  `if (isset($c[$j]) || isset($l[$j]) && isset($m) && $m['g'] <= $n['g']+$w)`

  Then we can remove the `unset($c[$j])`.
- `$m['g']` in this condition should be the *g*-score of the current neighbour indexed by `$j`. But `$m` has whatever value is left over from the previous loop: the node corresponding to `$j` on a previous iteration.

  What we need is a way to find a node and its *g*-score by node index. We can store the node in the `$l` array: instead of `$l[$j] = TRUE` we do `$l[$j] = $m` and the above condition becomes

  `if (isset($c[$j]) || isset($l[$j]) && $l[$j]['g'] <= $n['g']+$w)`
- Now the tricky bit. If the node we just found is not in the open set, we add it there (that's the `$o->push` and `$l[$j] =`).

  However, if it is in the open set we just found a better path to it, so we must update it. The code doesn't do this and it's tricky because the priority queue doesn't provide a routine for increasing the priority of an element. However, we can rebuild the priority queue completely and the last bit of code in the inner loop becomes

  `if (! isset($l[$j])) {`
     `$o->push($m, -$m['f']);`
     `$l[$j] = $m; // add a new element`
  `} else {`
     `$l[$j] = $m; // replace existing element`
     `$o = new PQueue();`
     `foreach ($l as $m)`
        `$o->push($m, -$m['f']);`
  `}`

  This is not terribly efficient, but it's a starting point. Changing an element in a priority queue isn't efficient anyway, because you first have to *find* it.

---

Even without these changes the algorithm does find a path, just not the best path. You can see it in the mentioned mazes:

- In the `crazy` maze in the third inner circuit: the taken upper path around is slightly longer than the lower path would have been because of the obstacles on the left.
- In the `big` maze in the upper-right part of the path there's an unnecessary  loop up.

---

Since this was on my mind, I implemented my own version of the algorithm and posted it in an answer to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5112111/a-search-algorithm-in-php/5169905#5169905).

Comment: is there any one other bug that you can see?

Comment: @EquinoX – The rest of `PQueue` looks fine; haven't looked at A* yet.

Comment: if you can revise the code and paste it above, I'll reward you with the bounty.. this might be set as a community wiki as well