# Adding non monotonic heuristics to A* php implimentation

Tags: php, path-finding, a-star, heuristics

I'm using aaz's [A* search algorithm in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5112111/a-search-algorithm-in-php/5169905#5169905) to help me find the shortest route accross a 3D graph of nodes.

It does it well but what it returns is the first route it finds which may not be the optimum.  As the node set is 3D, the heuristic is non monotonic.  How would I go about adapting this implimentation to search for the optimum route not just the shortest?

```
class astar extends database
{
// Binary min-heap with element values stored separately

var $map = array();
var $r;  //  Range to jump
var $d;  //  distance between $start and $target
var $x;  //  x co-ords of $start
var $y;  //  y co-ords of $start
var $z;  //  z co-ords of $start


function heap_float(&$heap, &$values, $i, $index) {
    for (; $i; $i = $j) {
        $j = ($i + $i%2)/2 - 1;
        if ($values[$heap[$j]] < $values[$index])
            break;
        $heap[$i] = $heap[$j];
    }
    $heap[$i] = $index;
}

function heap_push(&$heap, &$values, $index) {
    $this->heap_float($heap, $values, count($heap), $index);
}

function heap_raise(&$heap, &$values, $index) {
    $this->heap_float($heap, $values, array_search($index, $heap), $index);
}

function heap_pop(&$heap, &$values) {
    $front = $heap[0];
    $index = array_pop($heap);
    $n = count($heap);
    if ($n) {
        for ($i = 0;; $i = $j) {
            $j = $i*2 + 1;
            if ($j >= $n)
                break;
            if ($j+1 < $n && $values[$heap[$j+1]] < $values[$heap[$j]])
                ++$j;
            if ($values[$index] < $values[$heap[$j]])
                break;
            $heap[$i] = $heap[$j];
        }
        $heap[$i] = $index;
    }
    return $front;
}

function a_star($start, $target) {
    $open_heap = array($start); // binary min-heap of indexes with values in $f
    $open      = array($start => TRUE); // set of indexes
    $closed    = array();               // set of indexes

    $g[$start] = 0;
    $d[$start] = 0;
    $h[$start] = $this->heuristic($start, $target);
    $f[$start] = $g[$start] + $h[$start];
    while ($open) {
        $i = $this->heap_pop($open_heap, $f);
        unset($open[$i]);
        $closed[$i] = TRUE;

        if ($i == $target) {
            $path = array();
            for (; $i != $start; $i = $from[$i])
                $path[] = $i;
            return array_reverse($path);
        }

        foreach ($this->neighbors($i) as $j => $rng)
            if (!array_key_exists($j, $closed))
                if (!array_key_exists($j, $open) || $d[$i] + $rng < $d[$j])     {
                    $d[$j] = $d[$i]+$rng;
                    $g[$j] = $g[$i] + 1;
                    $h[$j] = $this->heuristic($j, $target);
                    $f[$j] = $g[$j] + $h[$j];
                    $from[$j] = $i;

                    if (!array_key_exists($j, $open)) {
                        $open[$j] = TRUE;
                        $this->heap_push($open_heap, $f, $j);
                    } else
                        $this->heap_raise($open_heap, $f, $j);
                }
    }

    return FALSE;
}

function jumpRange($i, $j){

    $sx = $this->map[$i]->x;
    $sy = $this->map[$i]->y;
    $sz = $this->map[$i]->z;
    $dx = $this->map[$j]->x;
    $dy = $this->map[$j]->y;
    $dz = $this->map[$j]->z;

    return sqrt((($sx-$dx)*($sx-$dx)) + (($sy-$dy)*($sy-$dy)) + (($sz-$dz)*($sz-$dz)))/9460730472580800;
}

function heuristic($i, $j) {

    $rng = $this->jumpRange($i, $j);
    return ceil($rng/$this->r);
}

function neighbors($sysID)
{
    $neighbors = array();
    foreach($this->map as $solarSystemID=>$system)
    {
        $rng = $this->jumpRange($sysID,$solarSystemID);
        $j = ceil($rng/$this->r);
        $this->map[$solarSystemID]->h = $j;
        if($j == 1 && $this->map[$solarSystemID]->s)
        {
            $neighbors[$solarSystemID] = $rng;
        }
    }
    arsort($neighbors);
    return $neighbors;
}

function fillMap()
{
    $res = $this->query("SELECT * FROM mapSolarSystems WHERE SQRT(
  (
   ($this->x-x)*($this->x-x)
  ) + (
   ($this->y-y)*($this->y-y)
  ) + (
   ($this->z-z)*($this->z-z)
  )
 )/9460730472580800 <= '$this->d'","SELECT");
    while($line=mysql_fetch_object($res))
    {
        $this->map[$line->solarSystemID] = $line;
        $this->map[$line->solarSystemID]->h = 0;
        $this->map[$line->solarSystemID]->s = false;
    }
    $res = $this->query("SELECT solarSystemID FROM staStations UNION SELECT solarSystemID FROM staConqureable","SELECT");
    while($line=mysql_fetch_object($res))
    {
        if(isset($this->map[$line->solarSystemID]))
            $this->map[$line->solarSystemID]->s = true;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your heuristic seems to be the straight line distance which is monotone. 
Within your a_star method, you never check if there are currently any nodes that are cheaper.

You could modify your $open_heap array to also track cost and instead of just popping off the front node on each iteration, pop off the cheapest.

Comment: I thought it was doing that with  if (!array_key_exists($j, $open) || $d[$i] + $rng < $d[$j]) but apparently not

I'll have a look at what I can do with the $open_heap...  The only issue that I see with popping off the cheapest is that in some cases it would be the cheapest that give the route the smallest distance to travel.  EG the 2nd to last hop I might only need to cover a small distance or halfway distance to get to $target.

Comment: By pop I meant with your heap_pop method that always returns the front node. If it were to return the cheapest node instead, as soon as you return the $target, you can be confident that you both reached your destination and found the best path.

Answer (score 0):

This question has been asked 2 years ago (at the time I'm answering it) but there is an obvious misunderstanding in it that I want to address in my answer.

In simple terms: 
`A*` finds the `optimum` solution given an `admissible` heuristic function.

A heuristic function is `admissible` if it never overestimates.

For example look the following (rough) figure:

[image]

If h never (for any state in the search space) goes above the h* it's proven that `A*` will find the optimum solution given h as it's heuristic function.

So monotonicity doesn't affect optimality at all!

Then, **Q**:"*How would I go about adapting this implementation to search for the optimum route not just the shortest?*"

**A**: Unfortunately you've not provided what exactly do you mean by optimal, but nothing changes in general. Just change your heuristic function so that the most desire state be the optimal point and try it to be as sensible as possible while not overestimating  even for a single state.